# Understanding "while (getchar() != '\n')"

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

I'd like to gain a little better understanding of how things work in the background in regards to this command.

I started off with trying to prevent my application from failing when `scanf()` received a `char` instead of the `int` it was expecting. The solution provided to me was to add the line `while (getchar() != '\n');` to clear the input buffer.
And it worked. Great!

But since I was otherwise using `scanf()` and not `getchar()` I found it a bit confusing that I use a completely different command for input to clear the buffer.

I have been Googling it a bit and from what I can tell, `getchar()` uses `stdin` and that is the buffer that is being cleared with that command. That would by extension also mean that `scanf()` is also using `stdin` in that case.

Is that assumption correct?

Comment: Incidentally, it's not good practice to use `while(getchar() != '\n');`, as, in case of end of file (e.g. the user presses Ctrl-D or the file redirected to stdin ends) or another error it will loop indefinitely (`getchar()` returns `EOF` forever, and your loop never ends). In general you want something more like `int ch; while((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n');`.

Comment: You could use `scanf("%*[^\n]"); scanf("%*c");` instead too

Comment: It's **all in the docs**: [scanf()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html), [getch()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html)

Comment: Don't use `scanf()` for user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's the case. It is explicitly mentioned in the docs.

Quoting the `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.2

> The `fscanf` function reads input from the stream pointed to by `stream`, under control
>   of the string pointed to by format that specifies the admissible input sequences and how
>   they are to be converted for assignment, using subsequent arguments as pointers to the
>   objects to receive the converted input. [....]

and chapter §7.21.6.4

> The `scanf` function is equivalent to `fscanf` with the argument `stdin` interposed
>   before the arguments to `scanf`.

---

Just to add a bit on why you need [`getchar()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) to clear the `stdin` when `scanf()` also reads from `stdin`:

`scanf()` only reads from the input buffer if the matching is success, pointed to by format that specifies the admissible input sequences. In case, the matching fails, which is your case, supplying `char` where `int` is expected (most likely, user use of `%d` conversion specifier), the input in the buffer remains unread and eligible to be read by next call to `scanf()`.

Thus in case call to `scanf()` is made, it is always advised to check failure and clean up the buffer using `getchar()`, which reads the `stdin`, character by character and return the character read as an `unsigned char` cast to an `int` in every call, thereby consuming *any* entry in the buffer and clearing it.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been Googling it a bit and from what I can tell, 'getchar()'
>   uses 'stdin' and that is the buffer that is being cleared with that
>   command. That would by extension also mean that 'scanf' is also using
>   'stdin' in that case. Is that assumption correct?

Yes, that's correct.

According to the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) (emphasis mine):

> [scnaf] Reads data **from stdin** and stores them according to the parameter
>   format into the locations pointed by the additional arguments.